# Pentaho CDE Component

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I would like to create number values card in Pentaho CDE dashboard but I am not sure how to do and there does not seems to have a component for it. I was wonder how many others are able to achieve them.

Please do help me out!

Example of what i want :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not able to directly achieve using any of the components but we can always write HTML and CSS code, so by doing that you can achieve 110M,3M thing.
you can use Dial chart to achieve MachineHours functionality.